# Is automated source translation seen as beneficial and/or necessary?

Tags: translation

I have recently spent several years translating legacy FORTRAN into Java.  Prior to that, I found myself translating FORTRAN into C (for which I wrote a simple translation tool).  After all this work, I find myself wondering how many others are doing similar language-to-language translations and whether an automated way of doing so would be beneficial.

I know about F2C, For_C, F2J and others, as well as some of the translation sites, but none seem to be all that successful.  Having seen output from For_C, I can see why it just hasn't taken off.  While it is technically correct, it is very difficult to maintain.

So, I guess what I am wondering is if there were are tool that produced more maintainable, more grok-able code than the code I have seen, would developers use it?  Or are developers as jaded as many posts seem to indicate and unwilling to use generated code as it could never be as good as their manually translated code?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Obviously time restraints necessitate it sometimes, but...

Rarely is code written in one language going to translate well to another - every language has certain ways of doing things that are more suited to the constructs available / common libraries / etc.

Consider for example a program written in C as compared to something written in Python - certainly you can write for loops and iterate through things in Python just as easily as you can in C, but it is much simpler to use list comprehensions and take advantage of the features the language provides.

I'd be surprised to see an example of a reasonably sized program written in any language that could be translated into 'correct', well-maintainable code in any other.

Answer (score 1):

This was already covered to some extent in [Conversion of Fortran 77 code to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275458/conversion-of-fortran-77-code-to-c), but I'll take a stab at it here.

I think there's a lot of time wasted translating legacy code to new languages.  It takes a phenomenal amount of time and energy to do, and you introduce new bugs when you do it.

Joel mentioned why rewriting from scratch is a horrible idea in [Things you Should Never do Part I](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html), and though I realize that translating something to a new language isn't quite the same as rewriting from scratch, I claim it's close enough:

1. Automated translation tools aren't wonderful because you don't get anything maintainable out of them.  You pretty much have to know the *old* code to understand the *new* code, and then what have you gained?
2. To port something manually, you have to know how the code works to do it well.  Rewriting code is seldom done by the original developers, so you seldom get people who understand everything that's going on to do the rewrite.  I worked at a company where an outsource team was hired to translate an entire website backend from ColdFusion to JSP.  That project kept getting delayed and delayed because the port team didn't know the code at all.  Our guys never quite liked their design, and they never quite got it right, so there was constant iteration as everyone worked out all the issues that were solved in the original code.  Then, the porting itself took forever.
3. You also need to be familiar with really technical inconsistencies between languages.  People who are very familiar with two languages are rare.

For Fortran specifically, I now work at a place where there are millions of lines of legacy Fortran code, and no one here is about to rewrite it.  There's just too much risk.  Old bugs would have to be re-fixed, and there are hundreds of man-years that went into working out the math.  Nobody wants to introduce those kinds of bugs, and it's probably downright unsafe to do it.

Instead of porting, we have hybrid codes.  After all, you can link Fortran and C/C++, and if you make a C interface around your Fortran code, you can call it from Java.  Modern codes here have C/C++ components that make calls into old Fortran routines, and if you do it this way you get the added benefit that Fortran compilers are screaming fast, so the old code continues to run as fast as it ever did.

I think the best way to handle this is to do any porting you need to do incrementally.  Make a lightweight interface around your old fortran code and call the pieces you need, but only port things as you need them in the new part.  There are also component frameworks for integrating multi-language applications that can make this easier, but you can check out [Conversion of Fortran 77 code to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275458/conversion-of-fortran-77-code-to-c) for more on that.

Comment: Nobody ever said some sort of *partially* automated translation couldn't be implemented incrementally.  You're a essentially answering a completely different question, rather than the one the OP posted.   Ideally your answer would be for management, or those considering a strategic 'rewrite', not for someone who has no choice in their assigned tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Since programming is hard, no such tool can really exist.

If it was trivial to change one language into another, the idea of "compiler" would be moot.  You'd just map the language you liked into the language of the hardware, press the button and be done.

However, it's never that simple.  Each VM, each language, each API library adds nuances that are just impossible to automate.

" I can see why it just hasn't taken off. While it is technically correct, it is very difficult to maintain."

Correct for F2C as well as Fortran to machine language.  The object code generated from most compilers can't easily be read by people.  Either it's cruddy or it's highly optimized.  Either way, it doesn't look a thing like an expert human would write in the assembler language for that hardware.

If only compiling could be reduced to some XSLT-like transformations that preserved the clarity of the old language in the new language.  If there was only some universal *Lingua Franca* of computing that would be the Rosetta Stone of programming.

Until someone invents that *Lingua Franca* of computing, every language translation job will be hard and will lead to code that's "difficult to maintain" in the new language.

Comment: You're working against your premise, with this excerpt; "If it was trivial to change one language into another, the idea of "compiler" would be moot. You'd just map the language you liked into the language of the hardware"  For example, If the language I 'liked' was C, and the language of the hardware was machine code, and pressing the button was gcc with options.... this is the whole point of a compiler, and while I wouldn't ever call any code transformation trivial, your example is certainly possible.

Comment: You may have been referring to the difficulty and mystique of creating a compiler, and yes it's certainly far from trivial... but ground-breaking programs aren't usually trivial.  The real question is, are they actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've used f2c, and I agree with whoever wanted to name it cc2fc instead.  It isn't a way of transforming Fortran into anything vaguely usable as C.  It's a way of taking a C compiler and making a Fortran compiler out of it.

It did work just fine at taking that Fortran code and turning it (through C) to a Macintosh library I could call from Macintosh Common Lisp.  Those were the days.