# Coverting Fortran code to C++ code

Tags: c++, fortran

HI with best regards.

Is there any converter or peace of code or something like that to convert a FORTRAN code into C++ code.

regards.

Comment: When you mean convert, are you expecting to read and understand the converted output?

Comment: My friend,.. i have a large fortran code and because of more flexibility of C++ for parallel programming i want to rewritten it in C++ but the code is very large! so i want to just ease the way of rewritennig. thanks for your reply

Comment: f2c, for FORTRAN 77 to C.   Have you considered mixing Fortran and C++?  See the Fortran ISO_C_Binding.

Comment: Thanks my firend. i have a free format fortran code,... ad i will try both you mentioned,..many thanks ,...

Comment: Did you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275458/conversion-of-fortran-77-code-to-c?rq=1

Comment: More flexibility of C++ for parallel programming ?  That's a questionable reason for converting a code from Fortran to C++.

Comment: Yeah, Maybe you are right :)

Comment: From a close study of your other question it appears that your motive for converting code from Fortran to C++ is your failure, so far, to parallelise the Fortran successfully.  Don't be so dismissive of your own skills and hard work, I'm quite sure that you can learn how to successfully parallelise your Fortran in a (much) shorter period than it will take you to translate the code into C++.

Comment: IIRC f2c doesnt convert to c per se anyway, but wraps your fortran in a mess of macros. The result is not something you'd want to work with directly.  It served its purpose in the days before there were free fortran compilers.

Comment: TO High Performance Mark : Thank you very much dear High Performance Mark to give me hope and i agree with you completely.

Comment: TO george: Thank you goerge, Yeah you're right! i tested it. not beneficial at all!